# Get unique value from an array php

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I want to display only unique strings and I have this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT tags FROM videos";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
while ($rez = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array = array_filter(explode(',', $rez['tags']));
    $array = array_unique($array); 
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $value = ltrim($value);
        $value = str_replace(" ", "-", $value);
        echo '<a href="http://example.com/' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a><br>';
    }
}
```

I have put an `array_unique` like this:

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```

But it returns this:

```
word-word
word
word2
word3
word-word
```

It doesn't print only unique values. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($rez['tags']);`?

Comment: You can use SELECT DISTINCT tags... which will give you a unique dataset.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT i can't do because in tags, for each video i have tag1, tag2,tag3,tag4,tag5... @waterloomatt

Comment: `var_dump($rez['tags']);`  it show me all tags and before each nr of strings @loko

Comment: Can you explain better what do you expect from your code?

Comment: @user3266370 can you give me the response?

Comment: @user3266370 That's what happens when you don't normalize your database.

Answer (score 0):

1. Explode your string.
2. Trim outer spaces from each element.
3. Replace inner spaces with hyphen in each element.
4. Only keep non-empty elements.
5. Only keep unique elements (using double array_flip).
6. Display results.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6f6d87f8c61e062b6c69db49220c21c076bd4632))

```
while($rez=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array=explode(',',$rez['tags']);       // split into elements
    foreach($array as $v){
        $v=str_replace(" ","-",trim($v));   // remove outer spaces, replace inner spaces
        if($v){$clean[]=$v;}                // retain non-empty values
    }
    $clean=array_flip(array_flip($clean));  // double flip is faster than array_unique
    foreach($clean as $v){
        echo "<a href=\"http://example.com/$v\">$v</a><br>";
    }
}
```

---

---

Alternatively, you could do all of the value and html prep in the first foreach loop and then use implode to display the batch.  This will remove the potentially unnecessary trailing 
 from final element:

Code:

```
$rez['tags']=' ,  word , word-word, word2 , word word, word3,';
$array=explode(',',$rez['tags']);       // split into elements
foreach($array as $v){
    $v=str_replace(" ","-",trim($v));   // remove outer spaces, replace inner spaces
    if($v){
        $clean[]="<a href=\"http://example.com/$v\">$v</a>";  // prep non-empty values for display
    }
}
echo implode("<br>",array_unique($clean));
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://example.com/word">word</a><br>
<a href="http://example.com/word-word">word-word</a><br>
<a href="http://example.com/word2">word2</a><br>
<a href="http://example.com/word3">word3</a>
```

Comment: it show me like me first code, but i don't get unique tags

Comment: @user3266370 You never posted a raw string for us to play with.  Since you say that your code is successful, I've updated mine with some refinements.  In my demo, you will see that the raw string starts with a space then a comma.  This means after exploding, the first element will be a space. My method will remove this space, but yours will not because of where your array_filter is ordered in our code.  Please try my new code, I think you will find it successful/better.

Answer (score 0):

Think the problem is because the strings are being processed *after* the `array_unique` operation rather than before it. Try the following instead:

```
$sql = "SELECT tags FROM videos";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
while ($rez = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array = array_filter(explode(',', $rez['tags']));
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $value = ltrim($value);
        $value = str_replace(" ", "-", $value);
    }
    $array = array_unique($array); 
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo '<a href="http://example.com/' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a><br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved, i will post code may be will be good for someone!

```
$sql = "SELECT tags FROM videos";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$alltags=array();
while ($rez = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array = array_filter(explode(',', $rez['tags']));
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $value = ltrim($value);
        $value = str_replace(" ", "-", $value);
        $alltags[]=$value;
    }
}
$array=array_unique($alltags);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo '<a href="http://example.com/' . $value . '">' . $value . '</a><br>';
}
```